# Storing touppercase() value in cookie and retrieving it in jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I have a postcode lookup that stores a value as follows (using jQuery.cookie plugin)

```
$.cookie('delpostcode', $('#deliveryPostcode').val().toUpperCase(),{path: '/'});
```

This stores `GL53%200DW`

I then try and retrieve it a little later using:

```
$.cookie("delpostcode")
```

but this returns `[Object][object]`

Both values are set correctly on the setting page but I can't retrieve them on the page where i try to grab them. If put

```
$.cookie('delpostcode')
```

into the console in Chrome I get `URIError: URI malformed`

Edit:

This has been solved by adding

```
$.cookie.raw = true;
```

when I set my cookie. Any ideas why?

Comment: No, that just means it is an object. Log it to your browser’s console using console.log(), then you can see what it actually contains.

Comment: In Chrome I'm looking under Resources > Cookies and can see that the cookie is being set.

Answer (score 1):

Open your browser's debug console and check what

```
$('#deliveryPostcode').val()
```

returns, it is probably no string. if you try it with a string it works:

```
$.cookie('delpostcode', "GL53%200DW".toUpperCase(),{path: '/'});
undefined
$.cookie("delpostcode")
"GL53%200DW"
```

Comment: I think this is the problem. If I hard code a value it works (as it's a string). Could it be the `type` of value I'm setting rather than the actual value?

Comment: what do you get from alert("cookie:"+$.cookie("delpostcode")); and alert("input:"+$('#deliveryPostcode').val()); ?

Comment: Updated question. I get a URIError: URI malformed error on the page I try to read the cookie

Answer (score 0):

Here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHbcn/) with a working example, I don't see where is the problem. Here is the code I used:

```
$(function () {
    $("#setCookie").on("click", function () {
            alert($('#deliveryPostcode').val().toUpperCase());
        $.cookie('delpostcode', $('#deliveryPostcode').val().toUpperCase(), {
            path: '/'
        });
    });
    $("#getCookie").on("click", function () {
        alert($.cookie('delpostcode'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Indeed, this does work. Could the be affected by an ajax call?

Comment: Each cookie is referenced by its domain, do you have any issue regarding domains (i.e. do you change domain between setting cookie (e.g. http://localhost/) and getting the stored cookie(e.g. http://www.myTestDomain.com))?

Comment: This is running on a WAMP stack to I'm setting everything at /. The site sits in a subfolder /bumblebeez

Comment: I'm not referring to the path (/bumblebeez) but to the domain, that's what preceed the /. However that's only an hypothesis.